# page is loading slow in google chrome when i use select2. Working fine in IE11 & Firefox

Tags: jquery-select2

Using below select2 code it's slow only in chrome if we have more records.

```
if ('${attribute.displayComponentType}' == 'searchableSelect') {
    $('#${attributeSelector}').select2({
    minimumInputLength:2,
    allowClear : true,
    placeholder : ""
});
$(".select2-container").width('98%');
$('#${attributeSelector}_clear').bind('click', function(e){
    '#${attributeSelector}').select2('val', ''); 
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap Multiselect or Bootstrap [enter link description here](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)select